# Python-Django module import issue

Tags: python, django

I have JSON data coming through various external API's into my Django project. I have two apps, one called 'products' and other 'extract'.  Through product app, have created the database and rendered the views required. Objective of extract app is to parse the JSON data and create/update the fields in the Django database. I have this code saved in extract/views.py as shown below -

```
import json
import urllib2
from products.models import Product

url = " .........."
.............
for i in data[results]:
    Product.objects.get_or_create (...........)
```

The issue I am having is this code is working well in python shell. It is extracting all the JSON data and updating the database. But, when I run the script on the command line outside of Python shell, it is giving error - 'Import error: No module named products.models'.

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing the directory structure of your project. Anyway, I recommend reading some documentation about the `import` statement (how it works and what it does). Basically, `import` skims through the folders in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and looks for python modules (simple .py-files) and packages (folder with `__init__.py` in it). But again, read the docs and you'll be fine. This is a very common question/problem for Python newbies.

Comment: Thank you, will read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django requires you to run `python manage.py shell` in order for the `product` app's models and Django internals to be initialized.

Check out this [blog post by Stavros Korokithakis](http://www.stavros.io/posts/standalone-django-scripts-definitive-guide/) to convert your code into a standalone script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is with the directory set up. Make sure all your migrations are done as well as the initial folder has the paths to your apps. Possible you need to include the paths to each app in the other's settings.